# Как указать цвет первого <li> в списке элементов?

Tags: css

```
<span class="col-sm-6"> 
    {if $c->brands}
    <ul class="example">
        {foreach $c->brands as $b}      
                <li class="brand-mega-menu">        
                    <a {if $brand->id == $b->id}class="selected"{/if} href="brands/{$b->url}">{$b->name|escape}</a>         
                </li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>   
    {/if}
</span>
```

Как указать цвет первого `<li>` в списке элементов ? 
Через CSS `:first-child` не выходит, есть ли возможность реализовать с помощью js или другими путями ?

Comment: Дело в том что в меню используется скрипт jquery.splitter, он раскидывает колонки на два равных списка и при решении 

`код
li:first-child a {
  color: goldenrod;
}
`

он красит соответственно две первые ссылки каждой колонки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, не выходило из-за того, что нужно было указывать цвет для элемента `a`, а не `li`.

Вот так все прекрасно работает:

```css
li:first-child a {
  color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
  <ul class="example">    
    <li class="brand-mega-menu">        
      <a href="/brands/1">Brand 1</a>         
    </li> 
    <li class="brand-mega-menu">        
      <a href="/brands/2">Brand 2</a>         
    </li> 
    <li class="brand-mega-menu">        
      <a href="/brands/3">Brand 3</a>         
    </li> 
    <li class="brand-mega-menu">        
      <a href="/brands/4">Brand 4</a>         
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что в моем коде используется `div` вместо `span`.
Вкладывать блочные элементы внутрь строчных некорректно.

Вольный перевод [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values):

> #### Случаи, когда стили по умолчанию могут привести к путанице
>
> У некоторых элементов есть стандартные стили или поведения, комбинации
>   которых, скорее всего, приведут к путанице. Использование запутанных
>   комбинаций запрещено, в случае существования эквивалентных
>   альтернатив.
>
> Например, элементы `div` отображаются в виде блоков, а `span` элементы
>   в виде строк. Размещение блоков внутри строк приводит к путанице; так
>   как и размещение `div` элементов внутри других `div` элементов, и
>   размещение `span` элементов внутри других `span` элементов, и
>   размещение `span` элементов внутри `div` элементов служит той же цели,
>   что и размещение `div` элементов внутри `span` элементов, но только
>   последний вариант служит примером размещения блока внутри строки и
>   именно последнее сочетание запрещено к использованию.
>
> Другой пример: нельзя вкладывать интерактивные элементы друг в друга. Например,
>   элемент `button` не может содержать элемент `textarea`.   Это сделано
>   потому, что подобная вложенность интерактивных элементов сбивала бы
>   пользователей с толку.

Единственное исключение: элемент `a` в HTML5.
Он может содержать внутри себя элемент `div`.